# Coffescript show alert when clicking on element?

Tags: coffeescript

I have this code

```
$ ->
        $('h1').click ->
      alert "I knew it!"

  init()
```

What's wrong with it?nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but probablt your code is formatted inproperly (what is important in coffeescript). Callback for `click` event must be nested (otherwise passed callback is an empty function)

```
$ ->
  $('h1').click ->
    alert("I knew it!")

  init()
```